# Setting max height for only one ConstraintLayout chain view

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have two views in a vertical chain in `ConstraintLayout` with `spread_inside` chain style. I want to set a max height using `layout_constraintHeight_max` for the first view only, but since it's the head of the chain it applies to all chained views.

How do I only apply a max height constraint to the first view of the chain?

Comment: That behavior is counter-intuitive. Why have a chain at all with just two views? Can you constrain the top view to the top with the max height set and constrain the bottom view to the bottom of the top view with creating a chain? You can then set whatever size you want on the bottom view. What do you expect the height of the bottom view to be in the current setup?

Comment: I need the chain to divide the available vertical space between two expandable views. Without the chain one of the views will expand to take all of the vertical space/max height constraint without considering how much space the other view needs.

Comment: The behaviour I want: 

In case of abundant vertical space: the top view expands to maximum of 200dp, the bottom view expands to take the rest of the vertical space.

In case of limited vertical space: the bottom view contracts to its minimum height, the top view remains at 200dp as long as possible, then starts contracting up to 0dp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That behavior of `layout_constraintHeight_max` is counter-intuitive. Try the following layout that should simulate a chain without the annoying `layout_constraintHeight_max` behavior. It uses a barrier to mark the top of the bottom view.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/topView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/barrier"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_max="200dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="This is the top view." />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bottomView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_min="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/topView"
        tools:text="This is the bottom view." />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="top"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="bottomView" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

You say that the top view can shrink down to `0dp`. If you mean zero height, then the foregoing may not go that far by itself.

Comment: Thanks, this works! Although I believe `topView` is meant to reference `barrier` instead of `bottomView`. And the the height of `topView` should be `0dp`.